# Switching circuit based on clock

Tags: transistors, multivibrator, monostable

[image]

I have attached the timing diagram. I want something similar to monostable multivibrator but with so additional features. don't know how the circuit will be.

Case 1:
I want the output to go high at the rising edge of the input, output stays high as long as the input is high but output will be pulled down after 500ms even if the input is high.

Case 2:
Output should go low if the input is less the 500ms, i.e. if the Input is of 300ms the output will also be of 300ms.

It can be easily done with micro-controller but i want some transistor or 555 solution if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard one-shot configured to 500ms and an 'and' gate should do the trick. Have the input signal and output of oneshot feed into the 'and' gate.